# Error while trying to borrow 2 fields from a struct wrapped in RefCell

Tags: rust

I have a struct which contains both data and a writer which will eventually be used to write the data. The struct is wrapped in a `RefCell`. Here's a small reproduction:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::io::Write;

struct Data {
    string: String,
}

struct S {
    data: Data,
    writer: Vec<u8>,
}

fn write(s: RefCell<S>) {
    let mut mut_s = s.borrow_mut();
    let str = &mut_s.data.string;
    mut_s.writer.write(str.as_bytes());
}
```

The compiler is angry:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `mut_s` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src\main.rs:16:5
   |
15 |     let str = &mut_s.data.string;
   |                ----- immutable borrow occurs here
16 |     mut_s.writer.write(str.as_bytes());
   |     ^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
17 | }
   | - immutable borrow ends here
```

Is there a different API I should use?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can manually invoke `DerefMut` and then save the resulting reference:

```
fn write(s: RefCell<S>) {
    let mut mut_s = s.borrow_mut();
    let mut tmp = &mut *mut_s; // Here
    let str = &tmp.data.string;
    tmp.writer.write(str.as_bytes());
}
```

Or in one line:

```
fn write(s: RefCell<S>) {
    let mut_s = &mut *s.borrow_mut(); // Here
    let str = &mut_s.data.string;
    mut_s.writer.write(str.as_bytes());
}
```

---

The problem is that [`borrow_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.borrow_mut) doesn't return your struct directly — it returns a [`RefMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefMut.html). Normally, this is transparent as this struct implements [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) and [`DerefMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.DerefMut.html), so any methods called on it are passed to the underlying type. The pseudo-expanded code looks something like this:

```
use std::cell::RefMut;
use std::ops::{Deref, DerefMut};

fn write(s: RefCell<S>) {
    let mut mut_s: RefMut<S> = s.borrow_mut();
    let str = &Deref::deref(&mut_s).data.string;
    DerefMut::deref_mut(&mut mut_s).writer.write(str.as_bytes());
}
```

Rust doesn't track field-level borrows across function calls (even for `Deref::deref` or `DerefMut::deref_mut`). This causes your error, as the `deref_mut` method would need to be called during the outstanding borrow from the previous `Deref::deref`.

The expanded version with the explicit borrow looks like this, with a single call to `Deref::deref_mut`:

```
use std::cell::RefMut;
use std::ops::DerefMut;

fn write(s: RefCell<S>) {
    let mut mut_s: RefMut<S> = s.borrow_mut();
    let tmp: &mut S = DerefMut::deref_mut(&mut mut_s);
    let str = &tmp.data.string;
    tmp.writer.write(str.as_bytes());
}
```

The compiler can then track that the two borrows from that temporary value are disjoint.

---

Note that this problem **isn't unique** to `RefCell`! Any type that implements [`DerefMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.DerefMut.html) can experience the same problem. Here's some from the standard library:

- `Box`
- `MutexGuard` (from [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html))
- `PeekMut` (from [`BinaryHeap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/binary_heap/struct.BinaryHeap.html))
- `RwLockWriteGuard` (from [`RwLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html))
- `String`
- `Vec`
- [`Pin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/struct.Pin.html)