# Mutating fields of Rc Refcell depending on its other internal fields

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, rc, refcell

I need to to iterate over a field of a struct inside Rc RefCell and modify some of its arguments according to its other field.
For example for the struct Foo:

```
pub struct Foo {
    pub foo1: Vec<bool>,
    pub foo2: Vec<i32>,
}
```

The following code panics:

```
fn main() {
    let foo_cell = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Foo { foo1: vec![true, false], foo2: vec![1, 2] }));
    foo_cell.borrow_mut().foo2.iter_mut().enumerate().for_each(|(idx, foo2)| {
        if foo_cell.borrow().foo1[idx] {
            *foo2 *= -1;
        }
    });
}
```

I can solve it by cloning foo1 before the mutable borrow and just using the clone inside the closure but that leads to unnecessary copying. In fact I basically need one mutable reference to foo2 and one immutable reference to foo1 (Please note this is simplified code and zipping the iterators won't do here). I understand the code doesn't comply with borrowing rules.. Is there a way to get this to work without cloning data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while trying to borrow 2 fields from a struct wrapped in RefCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47060266/error-while-trying-to-borrow-2-fields-from-a-struct-wrapped-in-refcell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to reborrow the `RefCell` on each loop iteration while it has already been borrowed to get the iterator over `foo2`. The solution for this is to use a single `foo_cell.borrow_mut()` before the loop and get separate borrows to `foo1` and `foo2`.

Note, the dereference on `foo_cell.borrow_mut()` is required to make this work.

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;

pub struct Foo {
    pub foo1: Vec<bool>,
    pub foo2: Vec<i32>,
}
fn main() {
    let foo_cell = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Foo {
        foo1: vec![true, false],
        foo2: vec![1, 2]
        
    }));
    // The dereference is required to get &mut Foo out of the RefMut<Foo>
    let borrow = &mut *foo_cell.borrow_mut();
    let foo1 = &borrow.foo1;

    borrow.foo2.iter_mut().enumerate().for_each(|(idx, foo2)| {
        if foo1[idx] {
            *foo2 *= -1;
        }
    });
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ed10bab0119cf36d9699514ce8fbc69c)

Comment: The crucial part is the explicit reborrow `&mut *`. The return value of `borrow_mut()` isn't just a reference, it's a `RefMut` struct that implements `Deref` and `DerefMut`. Everytime you access a field in the struct, the `deref()` and `deref_mut()` methods are called, which are opaque for the borrow checker, so it has to tag the whole struct as borrowed. Once you extract a single mutable reference to the whole struct, the borrow checker can see that you are accessing separate fields of the struct, since no opaque method calls are involved anymore.

Comment: It doesn't work to eliminate both variable assignments and inline both borrows https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9825e5c3318fd2810ec86307400a632a So I guess the borrow checker actually needs the bit of extra help to assign `let foo1 = &borrow.foo1;` outside of the closure. The mutable borrow can in fact be inlined as `borrow.foo2.iter_mut()...`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that worked. I kinda expected Ref and RefMut to work like regular references but I guess that's not the case

Comment: You can't inline both borrows because of the way variable capturing in closures work. Referencing `&borrow.foo1` inside the closure makes the closure capture `borrow` instead of just `borrow.foo1`. There is an [accepted RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2229-capture-disjoint-fields.md) to make this work at some point in the future.